# accessing live usb files from new hd ubuntu install

Tags: usb, live-usb

After my live USB (ubuntu 12.04 lts) refused to boot, I proceeded to install the same Ubuntu version on the laptop hard drive (a dual boot next to Win xp). This all went well without a hitch. Previous to this, I spent several weeks enjoying and exploring ubuntu from the usb pendrive. During this time I changed lots of settings and customized Firefox and more. Now, I'd like to import the home folder from the usb drive into the new install home folder on the hard disk, which is the purported folder that holds all those special settings to my knowledge.

Unfortunately and only being familiar with Windows file systems, the view of the usb file system from the new hdd install is totally perplexing. I can't find anything that looks anywhere close to the original file system. More, I can't find any of the files I had created and stored there, like the LibreOfficeCalc file that has all my passwords (this one is really discouraging) that was stored on the ubuntu desktop. Help me find this file alone and I'll bow down with full apologies to any and all computer gods. Being able to import all those customizing settings into the new install would be a major bonus also, but hey, I'm not greedy. I'll take the passwords file and be happy! And humble!

I would be very grateful for some clear, understandable help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu to the pendrive using Startup Disk Creator or UNetbootin, you have a Persistent install.

All of your persistent data is stored in a file named casper-rw.
You can mount this file and access this data as follows:

```
sudo mkdir /media/casper

sudo mount -o loop casper-rw /media/casper/
```